# Javascript: how can I reset this count down timer with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this count down timer, it uses `setInterval`:

```
var startTimer = function(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

    var intervalHandler = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        var timer_li = document.createElement("li");
        timer_li.id = "timer-li";
        timer_li.className = "navbar-text enabled";
        timer_li.title = "Autorefresh is enabled";
        timer_li.style.cursor = "pointer";
        timer_li.style.marginTop = "5px";

        if (timer_is_enabled) {
            console.log("Autorefreshing in: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            timer_li.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-refresh enabled'></i>";
            timer_li.title = "Autorefreshing in: " + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        } else {
            console.log("Autorefreshing disabled");
            timer_li.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-refresh changelog-icon'></i>";
            timer_li.title = "Autorefreshing is disabled";
        }

        if (minutes == "00" && seconds == "00" && timer_is_enabled) {
            manageTimer();
        }

        // button to enable/disable the timer
        timer_li.addEventListener("click", function(){
            timer_is_enabled = !timer_is_enabled;
        });

        if(document.getElementById("timer-li")) {
            document.getElementById("timer-li").remove();
        }

        var navbar = $("#user");
        navbar.after(timer_li);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

I need to be able to reset on some event, for example when a certain type of link is clicked:

```
$(".main-tab").click(resetTimer);
```

I know I should probably use `clearInterval`, but I end up making a hugue mess in my code every time.

Any help on how to reset this timer when I click a button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var intervalHandler; // global var

var startTimer = function(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

    intervalHandler = setInterval(function () {
    ...
};
```

In your click handler, use `clearInterval(intervalHandler);`